# How to get data from a column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering how to get data from a column that has number in a label.

```
import pandas as pd
movies = pd.read_excel("movies.xlsx")
movies.head()
movies["2"]
```

[image: data table]
[image: error]

Comment: Hi and welcome, please include what `movies.head()` looks like

Comment: try without quotes movies[2]

Answer (score 0):

Since your dataframe has no specific label, Pandas input an int-based column title for you. So, you can just refer to the column as `movies[2]`

For example, here's a dataframe without a specific column label.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
test_size = (5, 2)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(rng.random(test_size))

          0         1
0  0.636962  0.269787
1  0.040974  0.016528
2  0.813270  0.912756
3  0.606636  0.729497
4  0.543625  0.935072
```

You can see the dataframe is automatically given 0 and 1 since I did not give any column labels. Such column labels are in type `int`.

```
df1[0]
0    0.636962
1    0.040974
2    0.813270
3    0.606636
4    0.543625
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for adding the example.

Instead of `movies["2"]` you can use `movies[2]` to access the column.

You can also use `movies.columns = [<column_names>]` to set the name of your columns.